# Angular . AppComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: No available FullCalendar view plugins

Tags: angular

I got the trouble in angular fullcanlendar module, i am sure i have typed 'npm install --save ng-fullcalendar'. The ng-fullcalendar shows in node_modules folder. but when i type 
in the app.component.html, the error shows.

```
AppComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: No available FullCalendar view plugins.
at reduceDateProfile (main.js:5565)
at reduce (main.js:5527)
at Calendar.reduce (main.js:6652)
at Calendar.dispatch (main.js:6610)
at main.js:6583
at Calendar.batchRendering (main.js:6673)
at Calendar.hydrate (main.js:6580)
at new Calendar (main.js:6490)
at CalendarComponent.push../node_modules/ng-fullcalendar/fesm5/ng-fullcalendar.js.CalendarComponent.ngAfterViewInit (ng-fullcalendar.js:91)
at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:22416)
```

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FullCalendarModule} from 'ng-fullcalendar';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {EventService} from './event.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FullCalendarModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [EventService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```html
<p>Display event : {{displayEvent | json}}</p>
<div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
  <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)" (eventDrop)="updateEvent($event.detail)"
                   (eventResize)="updateEvent($event.detail)" (clickButton)="clickButton($event.detail)"></ng-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

Comment: are you able to show your app.module.ts code?

Comment: k, i have edited. is any problem in my code?

Comment: how about your app.component.html? did you use it like `<ng-fullcalendar></ng-fullcalendar>`?

Comment: yes , edited...

Answer (score 0):

I found a working demo for Angular FullCalendar [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

So the important part is to have all the necessary imports and code in the specific files.

I've listed the files to check below:

```
app.module.ts
app.component.html
app.component.ts
```

**Update:** I have modified the working stackblitz demo and it is now using the [Angular Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular) implementation. Please use Angular's Fullcalendar plugin as the old ng-calendar is no longer supported and will be forgotten

Comment: i knew this demo, and i also checked all the dependencies and modules which i need to import, but it just didn't work.

Comment: can you add your package.json and app.component.ts in the question? I am leaning towards version discrepancy, or missing code and need to confirm that...

Comment: @OliverDeng I know it has been almost a month but were you able to play around the stackblitz implementation?